# How to run specific tests using setup.py?

Tags: python, pytest, setup.py

I want to create different scripts to run different suit of tests.

I have the following project structure:

```
/project
  /src   
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
  /tests
    __init__.py
    test_module1.py
    test_module2.py
```

I want to have something like follows in my `setup.py` file (if possible):

```py
setup(
  ...
  entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
      'test1=test.test_module1', # this is supposed to run all the tests that are in the test_module1.py module
    ]
  },
  ...
)
```

But I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`.